# Identify book - conflict between humans on sublight ship

Tags: story-identification, generation-ship

I read the book in the last 5 years.  My recollection is that it was written by one of the 2-tier masters of the Science Fiction genre.

The book starts as the person title "Teacher" is decanted.  The ship warns him to evacuate the region of the ship.  Teacher keeps barely escaping ruined portions of the ship as each section is sealed.  He sometimes watches as others also decanted die in vacuum.

The book reveals the ship is three cylinders in the shadow of a giant ball of deuterium fuel.  The ship is headed towards another star.  Two factions are fighting for control of the ship.  They are fighting over what to do when they get to the destination star system if intelligent life already exists there.

At least one cylinder is completely trashed and the cylinder in which Teacher was decanted is in very bad shape.  Teacher and the ragtag group he recruits along the way go to the third cylinder to find answers and eventually confront the leader of one of the factions.

Comment: What does "decanted" mean here? Are these liquid life-forms?

Comment: I used the word "decanted" to mean a human dumped out of a container filled with liquid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for *[Hull Zero Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hull_Zero_Three)* by [Greg Bear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greg_Bear) and released in 2010.

Excerpt from the Wikipedia article:

> A starship hurtles through the emptiness of space. Its destination – unknown. Its purpose – a mystery. Now, one man wakes up. Ripped from a dream of a new home-a new planet and the woman he was meant to love in his arms-he finds himself wet, naked, and freezing to death. The dark halls are full of monsters but trusting other survivors he meets might be the greater danger.

Here are a couple of reviews:

- [Alternate Worlds](http://www.alternative-worlds.com/index.php?s=hull%20three%20zero)
- [Orbit](http://www.orbitbooks.net/2010/05/03/cover-launch-hull-zero-three-by-greg-bear/)

Comment: Yes it is!  Thank you.

I loved the premise of the book and on-going mystery of it. I was disappointed in the resolution though.  I had a much better potential resolution to it.